# Magento mobile theme loading desktop theme for category and product pages

Tags: php, magento, mobile

My mobile theme is loading the desktop theme for the category and product pages but loads the correct mobile theme for all other pages. Has anyone here encountered this problem or have any suggestion? I have removed .html suffix from category and product pages but i'm not sure how this affects it.

Any pointers would be deeply appreciated.

Thanks